# I am getting error when using slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error when building my flutter app :

**The return type 'Future*' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context**

I am getting this error on some slider class

My code is like this:

Code:

```
Slider(
                value: position!.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                onChanged: (double value) {
                  return audioPlayer!.seek((value / 1000).roundToDouble());
                },
                min: 0.0,
                max: duration!.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is at this line

```
onChanged: (double value) {
    return audioPlayer!.seek((value / 1000).roundToDouble());
},
```

Is `audioPlayer!.seek` returns a `Future` ? if so, that's what the error message is telling you, the function expected a `void` as a return type but you returned a `Future`. So change it to this:

```
onChanged: (double value) async {
    return await audioPlayer!.seek((value / 1000).roundToDouble());
},
```